# What is the condition of showing Google's attribution on Google Maps API Android v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making map application which shows tile overlay map on Google Maps API Android v2.

I have to show copyright of overlay map, so I put textview at the bottom center of map.

But, at some bigger devices, Google maps API shows their own attribution, so Google's attribution and my attribution is overlapped.

I want to show my attribution at bottom when Google never show theirs, and show mine over theirs, when Google show theirs.
What is the condition of Google show their attribution?

Comment: You can't hide Google's attribution.  From their terms: (a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When Google provides this attribution, you must display it as provided through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.

Comment: What I mean is "add", not "hide".
Google shows only LOGO in small device (like phone), and show both LOGO and their attribution in big device (like tablet).

So, what I want to do is, show my attribution at bottom in small device, or show my attribution above Google's attribution in big device.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't do this.

From https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies:

> If your application displays data from the Places API on a Google Map,
>   then the Google logo will be included and may not be altered.
>   Applications that display Places API data on the same screen as a
>   Google Map are not required to provide further attribution to Google.
>
> If your application displays data from the Places API on a page or
>   view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a Powered
>   by Google logo with that data. For example, if your application
>   displays Places API data on one tab, and a Google Map with that data
>   on another tab, the first tab must show the Powered by Google logo.

Comment: As I said in others comment, I "add" not "alter".